# Downloading RestComm Camel Gateway

Tags: telecommunication

i am trying to download the binary release for "RestComm Camel Gateway" using the following URL: https://mobicents.ci.cloudbees.com/job/RestComm-Camel-Gateway/ but the link is not working (HTTP Status 404 -) , this link is mentioned by "RestComm Camel Gateway" team in GitHub website (https://github.com/RestComm/camelgateway) , could you please help me to download this binary.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RestComm Camel Gateway](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36004975/restcomm-camel-gateway)

Comment: Hello All, any help for this issue ? , any way to download RestComm Camel Gateway ? thank you all.